# ggplot force solid lines

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a fairly long R script that produces a bunch of charts.  I'm hoping this is a fairly easy questions whose answer is independent of the exact data...

As an example, one of the plots is drawn by

```
natPlot <- smNatData %>% 
  ggplot(mapping = aes(x = as.numeric(DaysSince), y = infRate)) +
  geom_line(aes(color=abbv, linetype=abbv),show.legend = FALSE) +
  geom_point(data = NatEndpoints,size = 1.5,shape = 21,
             aes(color = Base,fill = Base), show.legend = FALSE) +
  geom_label_repel(data=NatEndpoints, aes(label=Base), show.legend = FALSE) +
  labs(x = "Days Since First Confirmed Case", 
       y = "% Local Population Infected", 
       title = "Infection rate of COVID-19, AFMC States vs National", 
       subtitle = paste("Data as of", format(max(smData$infected), "%A, %B %e, %y")), 
       caption = "HQ AFMC/A9A - Data: usafacts.org") +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(size = rel(1), face = "bold"),
        plot.subtitle = element_text(size = rel(0.7)),
        plot.caption = element_text(size = rel(1))) +
  facet_zoom(xy = Base != 'Massachusetts')
```

That produces this plot

[image]

Which is fine...except that I've been asked to make all of the lines "solid".  Is there a one-line way to force that?  Right now I have `linetype=abbv` in the geom_line aes()...

I've seen some solutions that look like

```
scale_linetype_manual(values=c("twodash", "dotted"))+
scale_color_manual(values=c('#999999','#E69F00'))
```

but I'd rather not have to manually specify all 10 lines...

Comment: So why do you have `linetype=abbv` if you want only one line type? It would seem like taking that would would solve the problem.

Comment: I'd still like them to be colored by abbv, just with solid lines

Comment: Well, you still have `color=abbv`, just take out the `linetype=abbv` part. Those are two separate properties.

Comment: i just did that :( man do I feel dumb....thanks!